# My table is adding an extra row when being constructed dynamically with a for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So im making a pixel art maker with javascript/jquery, where the user selects the grid size, and chooses their color. The grid should be perfect squares on top of each other through tr elements in a table. After each new row is created there is a gap between the rows on the bottom and top and the developer tools are showing an extra tr element being added.

Here is the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/logikevcover/t9ezz3b9/

```
// Define the variables for the color picker id and size picker id
let colorPicker = document.getElementById('colorPicker');
let sizePicker = $('#sizePicker');
colorPicker.addEventListener("change", watchColorPicker, false);

function watchColorPicker(event) {
    document.querySelectorAll('tr').forEach(function (tr){
        tr.style.color = event.target.value;
    });
}

// Size picker event handler which calls the makeGrid function
sizePicker.submit('click', function(){
    event.preventDefault();
    makeGrid();
});

// Sets the background color of the clicked td items to the color 
selected
$('#pixel_canvas').on('click', 'td', function(){
    $(this).css('backgroundColor', colorPicker.value);
});

// Creates the function to accept user input values to 
// define the size of the grid
function makeGrid() {
let gridHeight = $('#input_height').val();
let gridWidth =  $('#input_width').val();
let gridTable = $('#pixel_canvas');
let gridBody = '';

    for (let i = 0; i < gridHeight; i++) {
        gridBody += '<tr></tr>';
        for (let j = 0; j < gridWidth; j++) {
            gridBody += '<td></td>';
            gridBody += gridWidth[i] + gridHeight[j];
        }
    }
    gridTable.append(gridBody);
}
```

Comment: `gridBody += gridWidth[i] + gridHeight[j];` aka `<tr></tr><td></td>####`

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that you are closing your `<tr>` element before adding the `<td>` elements in your `gridBody` variable. Here is how you can fix this-

```
for (let i = 0; i < gridHeight; i++) {
    gridBody += '<tr>';
    for (let j = 0; j < gridWidth; j++) {
        gridBody += '<td></td>';
        gridBody += gridWidth[i] + gridHeight[j];
    }
    gridBody += '</tr>';
}
```

Working fiddle here - https://jsfiddle.net/t9ezz3b9/1/